# Python - simultaneously called REST API with rate-limiting

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, rate-limiting

I'm using a REST API with python3 which the limitation that for example I can just send 1 request each second. So the code is like:

```
for something in ListOfSomethings:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("example.com") 
    url = f"/api/somethings/{ListOfSomethings['id']}"
    conn.request("GET", url, payload, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    doMagic(res)
    time.sleep(1)
```

which work for one script.

But I have >20 different script all at different time schedulers, frequencies using the same API and then I run in this "HTTP 503 Rate Limit Exceeded"-Error.

Of course I could set the sleeping time so e.g. 20s but that very inefficient.

My idea would be something like a "MainApiHanlder.py" which runs all the time and gets request added to its queue. Every second it would send a request and return the response data.

The other scripts like "client1.py" - "clients20.py" "import" or in some way can add requests to the queue an can like async wait this the response is ready and can work with the response.

Do you have some ideas how to implement this or maybe in general other toughts about this issue?

---

Edit:
Thanks Booboo!

Unfortunately when I uses your script in 3 instance they run parallel and don't wait for each other e.g.:

```
Prints A:
task 0 at time 1685488098.8678958
task 1 at time 1685488099.8622599
task 2 at time 1685488100.8794386
task 3 at time 1685488101.8864574
task 4 at time 1685488102.9166281
task 5 at time 1685488103.9323702
task 6 at time 1685488104.9337478
task 7 at time 1685488105.9634092
task 8 at time 1685488106.9668365
task 9 at time 1685488107.9878469

Prints B:
task 0 at time 1685488099.687939
task 1 at time 1685488100.6912873
task 2 at time 1685488101.6991315
task 3 at time 1685488102.7152894
task 4 at time 1685488103.7455194
task 5 at time 1685488104.746891
task 6 at time 1685488105.774543
task 7 at time 1685488106.77701
task 8 at time 1685488107.8002963
task 9 at time 1685488108.8180158


Prints C:
task 0 at time 1685488100.5810971
task 1 at time 1685488101.5889332
task 2 at time 1685488102.5920835
task 3 at time 1685488103.6065595
task 4 at time 1685488104.6216643
task 5 at time 1685488105.651114
task 6 at time 1685488106.652704
task 7 at time 1685488107.6758645
task 8 at time 1685488108.6943634
task 9 at time 1685488109.713497
```

To clarify it, my issue can be only solve by something like this I think:

```
t0 - nothing happens
--> A wants to send 5 requests
t1 - A1 sent & received
t2 - A2 sent & received
--> B wants to send 3 requests
t3 - A3 sent & received
t4 - A4 sent & received
--> C wants to send 1 requests
t5 - A5 sent & received
t6 - B1 sent & received
t7 - B2 sent & received
t8 - B3 sent & received
t9 - C1 sent & received
t10 - nothing happens
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following `Throttle` class. Create an instance specifying how many calls can be made in how many seconds. Examples:

1. 1 call per second: `throttler = Throttler(call_count=1, period=1.0)`
2. 10 calls every 30 seconds: `throttler = Throttler(call_count=10, period=30.0)

For the most accurate timing place the call to method  `throttle` *immediately* before your API call that needs to be "throttled." If that is not convenient, then you might want to increase the *period* argument value to be on the safe side and not exceed the limit (perhaps this is a good idea in any event depending on how forgiving the API being called is).

```py
from collections import deque
from threading import Lock
import time

class Throttler:
    def __init__(self, call_count, period=1.0):
        self._call_count = int(call_count)
        self._period = float(period)
        self._called_timestamps = deque()
        self._lock = Lock()

    def throttle(self):
        with self._lock:
            while True:
                now = time.monotonic()
                while self._called_timestamps:
                    time_left = self._called_timestamps[0] + self._period - now
                    if time_left >= 0:
                        break
                    self._called_timestamps.popleft()
                if len(self._called_timestamps) < self._call_count:
                    break
                time.sleep(time_left)
            self._called_timestamps.append(now)


def do_something(task):
    now = time.time() # time call is made
    # simulate waiting for call to be peformed:
    time.sleep(.5)
    return f'task {task} at time {time.time()}'

# Send one request per second
throttler = Throttler(call_count=1, period=1.0)

for task in range(10):
    ...
    # Place the next statement as close to the call that needs to be throttle (in your
    # example it would be the statement conn.request("GET", url, payload, headers))
    throttler.throttle()
    print(do_something(task))
```

Prints:

```None
task 0 at time 1685469349.307801
task 1 at time 1685469350.3182874
task 2 at time 1685469351.328539
task 3 at time 1685469352.3538253
task 4 at time 1685469353.3543231
task 5 at time 1685469354.3784668
task 6 at time 1685469355.3933942
task 7 at time 1685469356.4193935
task 8 at time 1685469357.4302855
task 9 at time 1685469358.4413586
```